# Appropriate operation to perform on strings with invalid characters before storing them as properties?

Tags: javascript

I have object of the kind:

```
{
  path: 'C:/example', // path is unique
  fileinfo: ...
}
```

I want to store this in a state object as:

```
{
  files: {
    byPath: {
      'C:/example': {
        path: 'C:/example', // path is unique
        fileinfo: ... 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, my problem is that I can't guarantee that all paths will be allowed as property names. My first idea was to has the property names before using them as keys. Then I figured that I could base64 encode them because that would likely be faster. I don't see any disadvantage.

What would be an appropriate operation to perform on the paths before storing them as properties? Maybe there is some transformation more specific to paths I could use, rather than a generic hash or encoding?

Comment: _I can't guarantee that all paths will be allowed as property names_  in which sense? can you please make an example of one of those values?

Comment: *All* strings are allowed as property names in JavaScript. There are no invalid characters.

Comment: @Bergi: I thought they weren't. Thank you for informing me. That solves my problem!